# Change product price on selection of custom option (checkbox)

Tags: magento-1.9, price, custom-options, product-list

I have displayed Magento products on my site's homepage. **Some products have some custom options of checkbox type.** I have displayed those custom options under the product image. But I do not have any idea **how to change particular product price** after checking or unchecking that custom option checkbox.

[image]

Here is the code which I have used to display custom options:

```
$options = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getProductOptionCollection($emq_product);

//for showing custom options
foreach($options as $o) {
    //echo $o->getTitle();
    $emq_type = $o->getType();
    if ($emq_type=="checkbox") {
        foreach($o->getValues() as $v) {
            echo $v->getTitle();
            echo "<input  id='".$emq_prod_id."' type='checkbox' class='emq_chk' price='". number_format($v->getPrice())."'/>";
        }                           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a price to the option, get a look at the screenshot
[image]

Comment: I have already assigned a  price to each custom option. but it is working on Product view page only not on this home page.

Answer (score 1):

custom option code will be

```
$options = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getProductOptionCollection($emq_product);

//for showing custom options
foreach ($options as $o) {
    //echo $o->getTitle();
    $emq_type = $o->getType();
    if ($emq_type=="checkbox") {
        foreach ($o->getValues() as $v) {
            echo $v->getTitle();
            echo "<input  id='".$emq_prod_id."' type='checkbox' class='emq_chk' onClick='changeprice(this,". number_format($v->getPrice()).",". $emq_product->getId()).",". $emq_product->getFinalPrice()).")' price='". number_format($v->getPrice())."'/>";
        }
    }
}
```

**add this after the for loop**

```
<script>
changeprice (check,price,product,final) {
    if(jQuery(check).is(":checked")) {
        //add var declaration
        var tot=parseFloat(price)+parseFloat(final);
        jQuery("#changeprice"+product).text( tot );;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: optionsPrice is not defined

Comment: can you paste you html too?

Comment: I have added the code. But I think it is not getting the js file.. DO you have any idea which js it needs for optionsPrice?

Comment: how you showing the price. i am talking about that.

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting you. I have added 'price' attribute in checkbox. Is that correct?

Comment: i am talking about 400 price of product. give that div id pricechange

Comment: <?php echo $_product->getFinalPrice(); ?>

Comment: cna you paste your full code so i can add function for that..

Comment: Actually.. that code is too big.. I am displaying magento products in flexslider.. and into each <li> product details are displayed like.. price, add to cart button and custom options..

Comment: ok then follow me with on this add div id on price 400 with product->id your id will look like that   pricechange4. 4 is product id

Comment: ok wait.. I will add one div with that id to price.

Comment: update the answer try it

Comment: Ok.. i  have added new id to  <span> i.e. for ex. #price_change59 for product of id 59. 
 jQuery('#59').removeAttr('onchange').change(function(){
if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
        var price=50; //add var declaration
        price_change59.chagePrice('opConfig',price);
        price_change59.reload();
}
    });


but it throws error.."Uncaught TypeError: price_change59.chagePrice is not a function"

Comment: i update the answer follow that and span don't take id

Comment: Hello.. You are great.. now after selecting checkbox.. price is changing under product image.. that is correct.. but when I click order button.. ( i.e. Add to cart).. it inserts product's original price in the cart.. (It should take updated price).

Comment: not it not work like that you have to add custom option too in cart so he can take price of that

Comment: Can you help me little bit more.. How to do it??

Comment: But on the product view page.. when I select the custom option checkbox.. It updates the product price.. and after clicking on Add To Cart.. It adds that product with the updated price!!

Comment: http://www.richardcastera.com/blog/magento-add-a-product-with-custom-options-to-the-cart-through-url-querystring follow this

Comment: I checked that link,
but for each Add to cart button, I have used : onclick='setLocation('". $emq_add_to_cart_link ."')

Where $emq_add_to_cart_link  is coming from =  Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);

Comment: no this will not work for custom option product

Comment: I have used Ajax Add To Cart.. So products are added to cart via ajax.

Comment: Can you suggest me any solution?

Comment: have to  look at ajax add to cart extension then say something

Comment: glad i can help